# importing DrawingManager from tomchentw/react-google-maps fails for create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-google-maps

In an app created via create-react-app using

```
import DrawingManager from "react-google-maps/src/lib/drawing/DrawingManager";
```

will fail with the error message

```
Module parse failed: /.../react-google-maps-test/node_modules/react-google-maps/src/lib/drawing/DrawingManager.js Unexpected token (77:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|   propTypes: {
|     ...controlledPropTypes,
|     ...defaultUncontrolledPropTypes,
|   },
```

Since create-react-app uses a strictely defined build-process I have little influence on the features used.
Object spread is supported by the app.

Is this an issue on the `tomchentw/react-google-maps` or on the `react-google-maps side`?
Can I get this running without ejecting?

(I am asking this question corresponding to an [issue](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/597) on SO as requested in the repo.)

Comment: can you try importing it like this `import { DrawingManager } from "react-google-maps";` please

Comment: I tried that too, but the `DrawingManager` is not defined in the index.js (7.3.0). It has to be imported from the libs `import DrawingManager from "react-google-maps/src/lib/drawing/DrawingManager";`

Comment: My mistake I think it needs to be `import { DrawingManager } from "react-google-maps/drawing"` according to [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps#drawingdrawingmanager)

Comment: @wellnoidea: What do you plan to do about the GitHub issue?
Do you think there is value in adding this answer there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling this, I ended up in [this issue](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/386). It suggests to do the following

```
import DrawingManager from 'react-google-maps/lib/drawing/DrawingManager'
```

Comment: The problem was the *src* which I overlooked in the first tests.

Comment: @wellnoidea: Just saw that you update the GitHub issue too. Cool

Comment: Careful here: WebStorm proposes the import from `src` and directly from `react-google-maps`. Both options will fail. The correct import is **not** proposed by WebStorm.